# MySQL configuration type?

Tags: mysql, dedicated-server, development-machine

I am installing MySQL and when it reaches the configuration step it is asking me to select from on of the following server configuration types:

- Development Machine
- Server Machine
- Dedicated Machine

I am new to mysql, the reason I am installing this is because I am making an application which will store data on a database using MySQL. Now, can someone explain what does these server configurable type mean and which one should I be selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only about setting up the initial `my.cnf` file. You can always change this later.

Generally server configurations allocate a lot more memory to MySQL than you would on your development machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically trying to pick the default memory use setting and configuration (over simplification, but good enough for now). If its on a shared system or you have no idea of the physical machine, start with development.

You can always edit the my.cnf to better optimize your setup